# Calling presentViewController:animated:completion: changed UIScrollView's bounds and frame

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I'm writing an iOS app that has a quite simply layout, one top container and one bottom container view referencing two different view controllers, and in the middle of the view, here's a UIScrollView which embeds a UIImageView.

[image: Basic Layout]

And I'm *NOT* using auto layout, here's the constraints I set for these parts:

Top container view:

[image: Top Container View]

Scroll view:

[image: Scroll View]

Bottom container view:

[image: Bottom Container View]

Everything works fine until I call

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.imageView.image, nil] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After this call, the `frame` and `bounds` property of UIScrollView were set to all 0s, and I'm confused about what is going wrong here.

Can somebody point it out for me? Big Thanks!

Comment: just for curiosity this happen also if you present a plain viewController?

Comment: @elio.d I don't know how to test it, if I use ``[self presentViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] init] animated:YES completion:nil];`` the old view simply disappears, and I don't know if this happens.. Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem, turned out I accidentally added the following code:

```
self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;

[self.scrollView removeConstraints:self.imageView.constraints];
[self.view removeConstraints:self.scrollView.constraints];
```

So even when I've unchecked the Auto Layout option in IB, it is still working behind the curtain.

Sorry for the bad question, I guess this kind of problems cannot be solved without reading through the whole tons of code.